# What state is preserved in the cell returned by UITableView:dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

When using UITableView:dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, can I make any assumptions about the state of the cell that is returned? For instance, if my UITableView only displays UITableViewCells with a font size of 18, can I set the font size once on the initial alloc code and assume it will also be set to 18 when returned from dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier? Is there any state I should never make assumptions about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, the `contentView` is never reset. Although all cells are automatically cleaned by the method:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
```

when the cell is dequeued, the `contentView` is **NOT** cleaned.

Comment: Thanks for calling out prepareForReuse. It suggests that overrides should never touch the contentView either.